# Gist or JSFiddle with not cached permalink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, gist

I see a JS bug in a library and want to show this to the maintainer of the library.

First I tried to create a gist. But I can't server HTML via github. Then I tried rawgit.com. But this cached the page. Updates to my code are not visible.

I would like to have a permalink to the latest version.

Then I tried JSFiddle. Same here. I could not find a way to have a permalink to the newest version.

How to serve a simple public page for a small HTML+JS snippet?

I guess I am missing a public service which offers this (or an option in JSFiddle).

My data:

1. simple HTML file, only a few bytes
2. a custom JS file, only a few bytes.
3. a external JS file (JS library)
4. jquery.

Comment: You can certainly create a permalink in JsFiddle - hit the save button.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ http://codepen.io/ - Flagging as off-topic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see the "save" button if the fiddle gets saved for the first time. Now I only see an "update" button. Everytime I press "update" the URL changes. The last URL part is a number which gets incremented with every press on the  "update" button. How to update the fiddle without getting a new URL?

Comment: You can't, every time you save you create a new version. You can use Fork instead to start a new branch. It's the same as any source control repo, such as SVN or Github.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way for JSFiddle:

You have to Update the fiddle, then click "Base". You need to create or fork the fiddle yourself before you see the "Base" or "Set as base" button.

Source: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55039/can-you-edit-a-jsfiddle-without-changing-its-url

The problem in my case was, that I created the fiddle myself. But I created it before I was logged in. Now I know how to handle this. The useability of JSFiddle could be improved.